# KnockoutJS ForEach Binding - Dynamic URLs

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to generate dynamic links from a JSON collection via KnockoutJS foreach binding.

Example:

```
<div class="profile-links">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: Types">
     <li>
       <a data-bind="attr: { href: 'https://myapp.com/?ref=' + text:TypeId }" />
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This generates the following exception from KnockoutJS

Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token :;

What's the proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 10):

```
<div class="profile-links">
  <ul data-bind="foreach: Types">
     <li>
       <a data-bind="attr: { href: 'https://myapp.com/?ref=' + TypeId }" />
     </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

You can reference the property without the "text:" prefix by just doing TypeId

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this. `add ()` at the end.
    `<a data-bind="attr: { href: 'https://myapp.com/?ref=' + TypeId() }" />`